# writing a Dictionary into a Oracle table

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, date, pyspark

I have a dictionary where in there's key pair value, and i need to write the dictionary into the oracle table, date in the table is not allowing to write the value its throwing an error.

Code:

```
Prod_id = '202001_201911_MIT_LZZ'
market_code = 'GT01'

transaction_dt = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
timestamp = "_" + transaction_dt.replace("-", "")

d = {}
d['ALERT_EXTRL_REF_ID'] = [alert_Id]
d['TXN_DT'] = [transaction_dt]
df_load_summary = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

df_load_summary["TXN_DT"] = df_load_summary["TXN_DT"].astype("datetime64[ns]")

write_to_oracle_cmt(df_load_summary,spark,'Table_to_write')
```

Getting an error while writing into Oracle:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

Comment: that is coming from one the table the value is - 2020-04-14

Comment: So `2020-04-14` in Oracle is interpreted as `2020 minus 4 minus 14` which is not a **DATE literal**.

Comment: What does `write_to_oracle_cmt` perform? How do you write to Oracle?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber its function that accepts 3 params: write_to_oracle_cmt(data, spark, table_name="tables")

Comment: The question was, *how does this function write to Oracle*? Which interface is used? You should post a *reproducible example*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

> transaction_dt = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

The return type of above output is "string" not "datetime".

```
>> transaction_dt = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>> print(transaction_dt)
2020-04-14
>> type(transaction_dt)
<class 'str'>
```

There is no need to format datetime and pass it as a string, pass the datetime value directly as **datatime** type:

```
>> type(datetime.datetime.now())
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Now let **cx_Oracle** handle it in the execute statement:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(:my_date)", {'my_date': datetime.datetime.now()})
```

There's some good explanation [here](https://developer.oracle.com/dsl/prez-python-times-and-dates.html).